# Drupal 7 Always Redirecting To Default Language

Tags: drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 installation with more modules than I can possible list, but most are I18N and SEO. Now when I go to `http:/my-site.com` I get redirected to `http:/my-site.com/en`, which is the default, even when the browser locale is set to another supported language (as configured in `admin/config/regional/language/configure`). For whatever reason, if a user with a defined language is logged in, it will work, only the browser detection seems off.

I tried disabling modules that could be the culprit, like Translation redirect and Global redirect, but to no avail. If I disable the URL language detection I don't get redirected, but I lose the ability to specify the language via URL. What I want is simply to either get redirected to the correct language, or to not get redirected at all.

Has anyone seen this behavior before and knows how to deal with it? Can anyone tell me how I could debug the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be affected by a bug in Drupal core. I had the same problem for a while and finally found the cause and a workaround for it.

It goes like this:

1. Add this code to a custom module (change "mymodule" to your modules' name):

   ```
   /**
    * Implements hook_language_negotiation_info_alter().
    *
    * Remove the 'cache' setting from LOCALE_LANGUAGE_NEGOTIATION_BROWSER since
    * the code that utilizes this setting will in fact prevent browser negotiation.
    */
   function mymodule_language_negotiation_info_alter(&$negotiation_info) {
       unset($negotiation_info[LOCALE_LANGUAGE_NEGOTIATION_BROWSER]['cache']);
   }
   ```
2. Clear all caches (e.g. "drush cc all")
3. Go to admin/config/regional/language/configure and press "Save settings" once
   (this will rebuild the variable 'language_negotiation_language').

Now browser language detection should work properly.

I'm also looking for a real solution but this requires changes in core and probably some discussion beforehand because of the nature of the bug. I've opened an issue here: [Browser language detection for anonymous requests is broken](https://drupal.org/node/2257843)

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Since I had to search a bit for the answer: Clearing the caches without Drush can be done via 'admin/config/development/performance'.

Comment: Glad it works! Btw. a generally very useful module is Administration menu (admin_menu). It adds a dropdown menu at the top. There the very first item in the very first menu is "Flush all caches". (When installing it, remember to disable the core Toolbar module).